# What console-based program is used during Ubuntu Server 18.04 installation?

Tags: server, system-installation, 18.04

I have been using `whiptail` for a while since it is a nice console-based interface.

But when I installed Ubuntu Server, the installing screen looks like this:

[image: New Ubuntu Server installing screen]

If they stopped using `whiptail`, what program are they using now?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was wondering the same thing and it looks like a new ncurses-based installer, developed by Canonical, called Subiquity.

Here's a blog post I found about it.
https://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=news_item&px=Ubuntu-Subiquity-November

And here's the GitHub repo.
https://github.com/CanonicalLtd/subiquity

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for, thank you. (Welcome to AskUbuntu!)